# Regular Expressions Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to find regular expression [.-] in field filial_name.

```
select uc.filial_name from MYTABLE uc
where regexp_like(uc.filial_name , '[.-]');

select uc.filial_name from MYTABLE uc
where uc.filial_name like  '%[.-]%';
```

The first variant is working. But the second is not.

How to fix second variant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second expression isn't regex , it is normal search and should be used be like '%text%' .

Try this

```
SELECT uc.filial_name FROM MYTABLE uc
where uc.filial_name like  '%.-%';
```

Comment: Regular Expression [.-] it is  . or -.  But your expression is . and -.

Comment: If u use like operator , regex wont kick in  , u can use a variant like
    SELECT uc.filial_name FROM MYTABLE uc
    where uc.filial_name like '%.%' or uc.filial_name like '%-&' ;

Comment: Like doesnt support regular expressions ?

Comment: yes , like supports simple pattern matching , while regexp_like was introduced to support regular expression pattern matching .